# Extract product model from Linux commands or Python script

Tags: python, regex, linux

I'm currently testing and gathering PCs' hardware information from the laptops that come from different vendors(Lenovo,Dell,HP...). I have my Linux Mint Live USB for this task.

Right now, I want to get info of product line, product model from the json file generated from

> lshw command

However, the result comes out in different ways.

For example:
Lenovo's Laptop:

```
{
  "id" : "mint",
  "class" : "system",
  "claimed" : true,
  "handle" : "DMI:000E",
  "description" : "Notebook",
  "product" : "2353ABU (LENOVO_MT_2353)",
  "vendor" : "LENOVO",
  "version" : "ThinkPad T430s",
  "serial" : "R9YC24W"
}
```

product line will be **ThinkPad**, and product model will be **T430s**

In Dell:

```
{
  "id" : "mint",
  "class" : "system",
  "claimed" : true,
  "handle" : "DMI:000E",
  "description" : "Notebook",
  "product" : "Latitude E6400",
  "vendor" : "Dell Inc",
  "version" : "01",
  "serial" : "R9TQ24W"
}
```

product line will be **Latitude** , and product model will be **E6400**

Same issue to HP:

```
 {
      "id" : "mint",
      "class" : "system",
      "claimed" : true,
      "handle" : "DMI:000E",
      "description" : "Notebook",
      "product" : "HP EliteBook 8460p",
      "vendor" : "HP",
      "version" : "03",
      "serial" : "RGAGE14W"
    }
```

product line will be **EliteBook**  , and product model will be **8460p**

As you can see, the product line and model located in different node and sometimes come with different format. I'm trying to filter out the result and get the output from different kind of laptops

my expected result:

> product line: "xxxx"
>
> product model: "xxxx"

Is there any better approaches to perform such tasks?

Thank you so much in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use an other command to find out the requiered information. 
Take a look at [this page](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/). For example you could try `inxi -Fx`

An other way is to format those information with python using string operators e.g if you only want an output with the information wich product/model it is you could use `in` to search for e.g. "dell" in the string.
Or you can use the bulit-in function `split()` and `find()`.

It would be helpful if you would tell us what you want to do with those information. Collect in a database, ...

Comment: inxi -Fx outputs the same format as lshw. String operator will be very helpful only if I knew what vendor's laptop I'm testing. Since I will be testing different vendor's maybe panasonic or Toshiba, bands are uncertain. It's not a good way to change the python code every time I get the new brand.

Comment: As I understand, you only need the information to print the model/product and a human reads the output? So lshw should be fine?! Or do you simply want a more comfortable way?

Comment: I want to turn them into json or dictionary format so I can pass those data to my web app

Comment: In my opinion are there only two ways: You create a database with all your products and search through the output. Or you use the information in the "product" output line. I would create a database because how should Python (or any other language) know, wich of the information is your product?